# PHP Quiz using array to generate questions. How to count points?

Tags: php

how can I count points in this quiz? Array shows correct answers but how can I access it later after submitting the form?

```
<?php $Questions = array(
1 => array(
    'Question' => 'What is 2+2:',
    'Answers' => array(
        'A' => '4',
        'B' => '5',
        'C' => 'Nothing'
    ),
    'CorrectAnswer' => 'A'
),
2 => array(
    'Question' => 'Where is Paris?',
    'Answers' => array(
        'A' => 'Somewhere',
        'B' => 'in Rome',
        'C' => 'in France'
    ),
    'CorrectAnswer' => 'C'
),
 3 => array(
    'Question' => 'What is water?',
    'Answers' => array(
        'A)' => 'hydrogen and nitrogen',
        'B)' => 'hydrogen and oxygen',
        'C)' => 'hydrocarbon and iron'
    ),
    'CorrectAnswer' => 'B'
)); ?>
```

And this is code to print the form: Purposely I would also like to "echo" correct answers in green and wrong answers in red on the next page.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="quizz" id="quiz">

<ol>
<?php foreach ($Questions as $QuestionNo => $Value){ ?>

<li>
    <h4><?php echo $Value['Question']; ?></h4>
    <?php 
        foreach ($Value['Answers'] as $Letter => $Answer){ 
        $Label = 'question-'.$QuestionNo.'-answers-'.$Letter;
    ?>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="answers[<?php echo $QuestionNo; ?>]" id="<?php echo $Label; ?>" value="<?php echo $Letter; ?>" />
        <label for="<?php echo $Label; ?>"><!--<?php echo $Letter; ?>)--> <?php echo $Answer; ?> </label>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</li>

<?php } ?>
</ol>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
</form>
```

So what is missing is code which I should use after user hit the submit button. I know how to do quiz without arrays but this one is challenging for me. I am a teacher, just want to improve my classes for my students.
Every help kindly appreciated :)

Comment: The form action is set to the same page so what is the `next page` and how are you intending to call it?

Comment: The `other page` needs to know the contents of the `$questions` array in order to mark the answers. Is that to be duplicated content or done via `includes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To post to the same page and mark next to the questions:

```
<?php 

    $questions = array(
        1=>array(
            'question' => 'What is 2+2?',
            'answers' => array(
                'a' => '4',
                'b' => '5',
                'c' => 'nothing'
            ),
            'correct' => 'a'
        ),
        2=>array(
            'question' => 'Where is paris?',
            'answers' => array(
                'a' => 'somewhere',
                'b' => 'in rome',
                'c' => 'in france'
            ),
            'correct' => 'c'
        ),
        3=>array(
            'question' => 'What is water?',
            'answers' => array(
                'a' => 'hydrogen and nitrogen',
                'b' => 'hydrogen and oxygen',
                'c' => 'hydrocarbon and iron'
            ),
            'correct' => 'b'
        )
    );
?>

<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        
        
        $score=0;
        $answers=array();
        
        foreach( $_POST['answers'] as $index => $answer ){
            if( array_key_exists( (int)$index, $questions ) ){
                if( $questions[ (int)$index ]['correct']==$answer ) {
                    $score++;
                }
                $answers[(int)$index]=array(
                    'question'  =>  $questions[ (int)$index ]['question'],
                    'answer'    =>  $answer,
                    'correct'   =>  $questions[ (int)$index ]['correct']==$answer
                );
            }
            
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" name="quizz" id="quiz">
            <?php
                if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
                    printf('You scored %s/%s',$score,count($questions));
                }
            ?>
            <ol>
            <?php foreach( $questions as $questionno => $value ){ ?>

            <li>
                <h4><?php 
                    echo $value['question'];
                    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
                        echo $answers[$questionno]['correct'] ? '<span style="color:green">Correct</span>' : '<span style="color:red">Incorrect</span>';
                        
                    }
                ?></h4>
                <?php 
                    foreach( $value['answers'] as $letter => $answer ){ 
                        $label = 'question-'.$questionno.'-answers-'.$letter;
                ?>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="answers[ <?php echo $questionno; ?> ]" id="<?php echo $label; ?>" value="<?php echo $letter; ?>" />
                    <label for="<?php echo $label; ?>"><!--<?php echo $letter; ?>)--> <?php echo $answer; ?> </label>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </li>

            <?php } ?>
            </ol>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

To POST the quiz to `a-n-other` page you need to know the questions and answers on that other page. To that end the easiest method to achive this might be to use an included file for both the quiz and the results pages.

The included file with questions ( questions.php )

```
<?php
    #questions.php

    $questions = array(
        1=>array(
            'question' => 'What is 2+2?',
            'answers' => array(
                'a' => '4',
                'b' => '5',
                'c' => 'nothing'
            ),
            'correct' => 'a'
        ),
        2=>array(
            'question' => 'Where is paris?',
            'answers' => array(
                'a' => 'somewhere',
                'b' => 'in rome',
                'c' => 'in france'
            ),
            'correct' => 'c'
        ),
        3=>array(
            'question' => 'What is water?',
            'answers' => array(
                'a' => 'hydrogen and nitrogen',
                'b' => 'hydrogen and oxygen',
                'c' => 'hydrocarbon and iron'
            ),
            'correct' => 'b'
        )
    );
?>
```

The quiz page that points the form to the results page rather than itself:

```
<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/questions.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action='quizresults.php' method="post">

            <ol>
            <?php foreach( $questions as $questionno => $value ){ ?>

            <li>
                <h4><?php echo $value['question']; ?></h4>
                <?php 
                    foreach( $value['answers'] as $letter => $answer ){ 
                        $label = 'question-'.$questionno.'-answers-'.$letter;
                ?>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="answers[ <?php echo $questionno; ?> ]" id="<?php echo $label; ?>" value="<?php echo $letter; ?>" />
                    <label for="<?php echo $label; ?>"><!--<?php echo $letter; ?>)--> <?php echo $answer; ?> </label>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </li>

            <?php } ?>
            </ol>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

And the page that is targeted by the form, `quizresults.php`

```
<?php
    #quiz results
    require __DIR__ . '/questions.php';
?>
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        
        $score=0;
        
        foreach( $_POST['answers'] as $index => $answer ){
            if( array_key_exists( (int)$index, $questions ) ){
                
                if( $questions[ (int)$index ]['correct']==$answer ) {
                    $score++;
                }
                $answers[(int)$index]=(object)array(
                    'question'  =>  $questions[ (int)$index ]['question'],
                    'answer'    =>  $answer,
                    'correct'   =>  $questions[ (int)$index ]['correct']==$answer
                );
            }
        }
        
        foreach($answers as $index => $arr){
            printf(
                '<div>[ Question %d ] %s Answer: %s %s</div>', 
                $index, 
                $arr->question, 
                $arr->answer, $arr->correct ? '<span style="color:green">Correct</span>' : '<span style="color:red">Incorrect</span>'
            );
        }
    }
?>
```

**Update:** As per comment that the actual answer should be coloured green/red

```
<?php
    #quiz results
    require __DIR__ . '/questions.php';
?>

<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        
        $score=0;
        
        foreach( $_POST['answers'] as $index => $answer ){
            if( array_key_exists( (int)$index, $questions ) ){
                
                if( $questions[ (int)$index ]['correct']==$answer ) {
                    $score++;
                }
                $answers[(int)$index]=(object)array(
                    'question'  =>  $questions[ (int)$index ]['question'],
                    'answer'    =>  $answer,
                    'correct'   =>  $questions[ (int)$index ]['correct']==$answer
                );
            }
        }
        
        
        
        echo '<ol>';
        
        $percentage=round( ( $score / count( $questions ) ) * 100, 1 );
        
        $message='Appalling!';
        if( $percentage > 25 )$message='Bad luck!';
        if( $percentage > 50 )$message='Well done!';
        if( $percentage > 75 )$message='Congratulations!';
        if( $percentage == 100 )$message='Outstanding!';
        
        
        printf('<h2>%s You scored: %d/%d ( %s%% )</h2>', $message, $score, count( $questions ), $percentage );
        
        foreach( $questions as $questionno => $value ){
            
            $options=array();
            
            foreach( $value['answers'] as $letter => $answer ){
                $label = 'question-'.$questionno.'-answers-'.$letter;
                $checked='';
                
                if( isset( $answers[ $questionno ] ) && trim( $answers[ $questionno ]->answer )==trim( $letter ) ){
                    switch( $answers[ $questionno ]->correct ){
                        case true:
                            $colour='green';
                            $adjective=' - Correct';                        
                        break;
                        case false:
                            $colour='red';
                            $adjective=' - Incorrect';                      
                        break;
                    }
                    $answer=sprintf('<span style="color:%s">%s%s</span>', $colour, $answer,$adjective );
                    $checked=' checked';
                }
                
                
                
                $options[]=sprintf(
                    '<div>
                        <input type="radio" name="answers[%1$d]" id="%2$s" value="%3$s" %5$s/>
                        <label for="%2$s">%4$s</label>
                    </div>',
                    $questionno,
                    $label,
                    $letter,
                    $answer,
                    $checked
                );
            }
            
            
            printf(
                '<li>
                    <h4>%s</h4>
                    %s
                </li>',
                $value['question'],
                implode(PHP_EOL,$options)
            );
        }
        echo '</ol><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">OK - Go back</a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is so kind of You!

Comment: perhaps consider accepting the answer if it helped?

Comment: Sure, I will try, it is my first time to use stackoverflow, I am learning how to use it.

Comment: And do you know how to mark correct answer in green color and wrong in red? I mean part of array (after it's printed) should change color after submit button, not a new text appearing next to the question.